# How to get the "this" value inside an on click function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, click, live

I want to use the live click function for my buttons so that it will be working on Ajax Loaded HTML, but then I learned that the new version for jQuery's live click -- `$(".button").live("click", function() {...})` -- is the one with `.on()` function.

Since on that syntax, the element is inside the parameter, I could not retrieve that element if my element is "this". Is there any way I could retrieve it?

```
$(".selection-item a").each(function(){
    var parent_selection = $(this).parents(".selection-item-wrapper");

    // $(this).click(function(){ //This is the original function which works fine EXCEPT on Ajax Loaded HTML
    $(parent_selection).on("click",this,function(){
        $(".selection-item a",parent_selection).removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");  //This does not target my desired element which is $(".selection-item a")'s this

        console.log( $(this) ); // The "this" value returns the parent_selection, I want it to return the particular "this" of $(".selection-item a") read from the .each() on top of my code
    });
});
```

This is my HTML. I am creating a simple item selection. That whenever I click on the image's anchor tag, I will add an "active" class to add css on it with borders to illustrate that the particular item was selected.

```
<div class="selection-item-wrapper">
    <div class="selection-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image1.png"></a>
        <h3>Item 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="selection-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image2.png"></a>
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="selection-item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="img/image3.png"></a>
        <h3>Item 3</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide you HTML too?

Comment: @ChiragVidani Thank you so much for the response. I updated the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys! but it now worked with no need of .each()... We just used the following:

```
$(document).on("click",".selection-item a",function(){
    var parent_selection = $(this).parents(".selection-item-wrapper");
    $(".selection-item a",parent_selection).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate `click` event to `a` elements and then refer to those using `this`:

```
$(parent_selection).on("click", "a", function(){
    // "this" will contain "a" element
    var $this = $(this);

    $(".selection-item a", parent_selection).removeClass("active");
    // Or maybe: $this.siblings("a").removeClass("active");

    $this.addClass("active");  // Add .active to "a"
    console.log( $this );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, man! I tried console logging inside and outside the function you said. But it does not enter inside the $(parent_selection).on("click", "a", function(){

Comment: OP is ajaxing, this isn't going to work. For some reason people think that .each will help :/

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I'm not 100% sure without html markup I am a little confused by the each.

Anyway I'd change the `.on` function to target the elements in a more specific way.

```
$('.selection-item').on("click","a",function(){
        $(".selection-item a").removeClass("active")
        var myself = $(this);
        myself.addClass('active');
        console.log( $(this) );
});
```

**Updated**

You say that you need it to work on ajaxed markup. Well, `.on` will only work if the top level selector:`$('.selection-item-wrapper')` was there on page load.

It **WILL NOT WORK** if you are trying to bind `.on` to ajax content. So without you giving me the entire markup before ajaxing in stuff I'll not be able to help. (I can, but its a bad ting to do). So give me all the code.

So here is the working code:

```
$('.selection-item-wrapper').on("click","a",function(){
    $(".selection-item a").removeClass("active")
    var myself = $(this);
    myself.addClass('active');
    console.log( myself );
    return false;
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa6Tp/) with a working example.

Just as a side note, there is no need to give the url's `javascript:void(0);` when you already have an event binded to them `$('.selection-item').on("click"`. So rather than add more difficult to maintain js in the code I've added `return false;` into the code. There are other ways to prevent the links default behaviour, `preventDefault()` for example. But for this situation `returning false` is fine.

Comment: Saftey, in short if you have need of any closures you'll still have access to the clicked element. But also, for performance. If you want to manipulate $(this) you have a nice sexy reference to it.

Comment: Sure. But in THIS code I do not see the need and it would stop the discussion about _this_ in this question quite nicely :)

Comment: All code should follow best practises, imo I believe this is correct so THIS code should include it ;) You never know where code will go, if you can write in a way that gives it longevity then you're crazy not to do it.

Comment: Hmm, I may be happy I do not have to maintain your code :) I prefer terseness when verbosity is not needed. If your code does the job, then `$(this).addClass('active');` is in my opinion less confusing. Not to you, but to the non-yous who come after

Comment: Fair enough, at least you know enough to remove the `var` and put `$(this)` there

Comment: @JamieHutber Thanks for the response! But even without the each(), I still need to use the "this" value.. And the output for this is still the parent which is the .selection-item in your code..

Comment: Have you got anywhere with all of the code? Trying to understand exactly what you're after :)

Comment: @JamieHutber it now worked with no need of .each()... I used $(document).on("click",".selection-item a",function(){ }); ..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".selection-item a").each(function(){
    var parent_selection = $(this).parents(".selection-item-wrapper");
    var that = this;  // HERE
    $(parent_selection).on("click",this,function(){
        $(".selection-item a",parent_selection).removeClass("active");
        $(that).addClass("active");  //This does not target my desired element which is     $(".selection-item a")'s this

        console.log( $(that) ); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually tried this and yet the "that" value returns all elements that points to this ".selection-item a"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   $(".selection-item a").each(function(i,el){
        var parent_selection = $(el).parents(".selection-item-wrapper");

        $(parent_selection).on("click",function(){
            $(".selection-item a",parent_selection).removeClass("active");
            $(el).addClass("active");   
        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. Same with Kamil T, The value "el" returns all the elements that points to ".selection-item a". :(

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$('.selection-item').click(function(){
 $('.selection-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/8PunU/)